# Checkbox click invalid data inside v-for loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to validate at least one need to check the checkbox.
I'm trying to validate when I clicked on checkbox through the loop.
When I checked one, the output is invalid return false in the first click. When I unchecked return true. But when I checked my sizes array data with vue-dev tools data is valid. I'm trying to find that bugs but I didn't find.
I don't know why.I would like to know that's why? Am I wrong?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     sizes:[
       {id:1,name:'small',ischeck:false,price:0},
        {id:2,name:'medium',ischeck:false,price:0},
        {id:3,name:'large',ischeck:false,price:0}        
      ],
      newval:[]
  },
  methods: {
    checkchanged(){
     for(var i=0;i<this.sizes.length;i++){           
       console.log(this.sizes[i].ischeck);
      }     
      
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span v-for="size in sizes">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="size.ischeck" :value="size.ischeck" 
    @click="checkchanged">
    <label>{{size.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" :disabled="!size.ischeck" v-model="size.price">
</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using `computed` property which you call `error` and hide/show the error message according to that property value:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     sizes:[
       {id:1,name:'small',ischeck:false,price:0},
        {id:2,name:'medium',ischeck:false,price:0},
        {id:3,name:'large',ischeck:false,price:0}        
      ],
      newval:[],
      
  },
  methods: {
    checkchanged(){
     for(var i=0;i<this.sizes.length;i++){           
       console.log(this.sizes[i].ischeck);
      }  
      
    }
  },
  computed:{
    error(){
      for(var i=0;i<this.sizes.length;i++){ 
      if(this.sizes[i].ischeck) return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app"  style="display :flex;flex-direction: column;">
<div v-for="size in sizes">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="size.ischeck" :value="size.ischeck" 
    @change="checkchanged">
    <label>{{size.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" :disabled="!size.ischeck" v-model="size.price">
    
</div>
   <div v-if="error"  style="color:red">
     there's an error !
   </div>
</div>
```

Finally you don't need to that event `@click="checkchanged"` you can use  `@change="checkchanged"` instead